# Spinning Ring on Adobe Acrobat at Startup

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I need some help trying to get Adobe Acrobat to work. A blue spinning ring appears 10-15 seconds after opening the app and it becomes stuck and unusable. Can't close the app without going into Task Manager. Have tried uninstalling and reinstalling after restarting computer. Even deleted background processes on Task Manager and deleted data on Registry Editor (for all Creative Cloud related apps). Logged in with a different account - same result. Account works on other computers though, so it could be a hardware problem but just want to check if there are any other software options I can try.

Comment: Tech support is off-topic. Sorry. Contact Adobe for tech support.